# How to get value of X to come up with a pre-defined target percentage

Tags: percentages, percentile

My title would be off, so I'll try to explain it as clear as I can.

Say I bought StockX at the price of X apiece.

== DURING BUYING ==

Let X = 10 as Unit Price of StockX

```
gross = qty x unit price(X)
charges = 10% of gross
total = gross + charges
```

eg.

```
gross = 100 x 10 = 1000
charges = (1000*.10) = 100
total = 1000 + 100 = 1100
```

Meaning, in order for me to own 100 units of StockX, I would need to pay for 11 apiece.

== DURING SELLING ==

Let X = 13.45 as Unit Price of StockX

```
gross = qty x unit price(X)
charges = 10% of gross
total = gross - charges
```

eg.

```
gross = 100 x 13.45 = 1345
charges = (1345*.10) = 134.5
total = 1345 - 134.5 = 1210.5

total gain = (1210.5-1100) = 110.5
gain% = (110.5/1100)*100 = +10.04% (positive gain)
```

In this case, I have to wait for the price of StockX to settle at 13.45 apiece before selling if I wanted to have a gain of 10% for my investment.

So say, if I want to have a 20% gain, what should be the price of X? How can I translate this into a formula to identify X if I wanted to take action at a certain percentage.

Also, what do you call this kind of mathematical problems? (Is this probability)?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: eg. for a 10% gain, Total Buying Cost * 1.1, this kind of yield 10% but I don't feel its right because I would miss to consider the sell charges which would eventually decrease the 10% gain.

Comment: First attempt should be to express the gain percentage $G$ as a mathematical function of $X$, the stock price.  Trying to that should help to decide the last point you raised, Is this probability?  In other words, if $X$ does not determine $G$ as an explicit function, then perhaps there is some probabilistic component you need to model.  You would then have a different kind of problem, in which the *expected value* of $G$ is a function of $X$.

Comment: @hardmath, X = function(G)?, please help elaborate.

Comment: No, if you thought that or had expressed $X = \text{function}(G)$, I'm sure you'd be happy.  It is possible that $G = \text{function}(X)$ and we have a problem to solve.  But I suspect you are dealing with circumstances in which the purchase price $X$ may be increased or decreased before the sale price is realized.  You have to decide if that is a matter of chance or a matter of known fact accounted for by your model.

Comment: you are dealing with circumstances in which the purchase price X may be increased or decreased before the sale price is realized - true. Somehow my problem could relate to a stop at loss trading method, but that just seems off because it doesn't regard the charges after the selling.

Comment: I guess and would think (for now) that there is no mathematical equivalent to solve my problem other than letting the computer do a series of computation and letting it point out that I've hit the specified percentage which I think will require some computational power and will go to waste but does the job.